# Sending an error in grails and reading it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, grails

Hi my question is how i would send an error from the grails side after a check, for example in a grails controller being called if i had (don't know if its correct):

```
     if(something){ return error #}
     else if(something){ return error #}
     else{ return error#}
```

And then what i would need to do in a js function so that it can receive said errors and then act upon it. ie. Error 200 continues as normal, error 400 renders a new page etc, just need to get to the part of reading this error.

Answer (score 0):

Simple stuff:

```
 def delPhoto() {
        Photos ph = Photos.get(params.id as Long)
        if (ph) {
           doSomething()
           //  return status 200
           render status:response.SC_OK
           return
        }
        //OtherWise return 404
        render status:response.SC_NOT_FOUND
    }
```

Now in your gsp java script

```
$.ajax({timeout:1000,cache:true,type: 'GET',url: "${g.createLink(controller: 'photos', action: 'delPhoto')}",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#uploads").html(data);
            }, 
 statusCode: {
                417: function() {
                    $('#field').css({'color':'white'});
                    $('#field').html("${g.message(code:'default.false.error')}")
                }
            },
 statusCode: {
                404: function() {
                    $('#field').css({'color':'white'});
                    $('#field').html("${g.message(code:'default.false.error')}")
                }
            },

            error: function (e) {
            }
        });

        });
```

So your ajax call then defines for each error message or success what things to update on the page

Comment: In the grails end you did 
render status:response.SC_OK
return
for the error 200, is there a way to send the number 200 for example response.status(200) would it work the same?

Comment: yep you could render status: 404 or a numeric value if you prefer. You can look up all the different statuses you can properly return here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html

Answer (score 0):

instead of returning status you can directly set your response status in you controller action like this

```
response.status = 401
```

and render anything you want.

And access your response status in your ajax success handler like below

```
$.ajax({
    //...        
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    } 
});
```