# Contents of Div Dialog Content shows even when Jquery Dialog isn't open

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I am using Grails 3.1.9 as the platform, my problem is that when the button Add Item has not been clicked, I can see the contents of the dialog box at the bottom of the page, and when the button is clicked, the contents disappear from the bottom. How do I prevent this from happening? Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Before Clicking Add Item Button
[image: This is before clicking Add Item Button]

After Clicking Add Item Button
[image: This is After Clicking Add Item Button]

show.gsp Code is:

```
<div id="dialogEntry" title="Item Entry">
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <form id="entryForm" action="" method="post" ><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" id="_method" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="invoice.id" value="${invoice.id}" />
                        <div class="fieldcontain required">
                        <label for="product">
                            <g:message code="orderItem.product.label" default="Product" />
                            <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" name="product" value="" required="" id="product" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="prodid" value="" />
                        <div class="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="quantityInStock">
                                Quantity in Stock
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" id="quantityInStock" value="" readonly="true" />
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='fieldcontain required'>
                        <label for='quantity'>Quantity
                        <span class='required-indicator'>*</span>
                        </label><input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" required="" min="1" id="quantity" />
                        </div>
                        <div class='fieldcontain required'>
                        <label for='price'>Price
                        <span class='required-indicator'>*</span>
                        </label><input type="number" name="price" value="" required="" step="0.01" min="1.00" id="price" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="totalAmount">
                                Total Amount
                            </label>
                            <input type="null" name="totalAmount" value="" id="totalAmount" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
<script>

            var editId;
            document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
            function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("add").innerHTML =
                        $( "#dialogEntry" ).dialog({
                            autoOpen: true,
                            modal: true,
                            width: 500,
                            buttons: [
                                {
                                    text: "Save",
                                    click: function() {
                                        var quantity = $('#quantity')[0].value;
                                        var quantityInStock = $('#quantityInStock')[0].value;
                                        if (quantity.length == 0) {
                                            alert('Quantity is required');
                                            $('#quantity')[0].focus();
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        if (parseInt(quantity) > parseInt(quantityInStock)) {
                                            alert('Quantity cannot be served as Quantity in Stock is just ' + quantityInStock);
                                            $('#quantity')[0].focus();
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                        var price = $('#price')[0].value;
                                        var prodid = $("#prodid")[0].value;
                                        // submit to server
                                        //var form = $('#entryForm')[0];
                                        if (editId != 0) {
                                            $.ajax({
                                                type: "POST",
                                                url: "${resource(dir:'orderItem/updatex')}/" + editId,
                                                data: {'productid':prodid, 'quantity':quantity, 'price':price},
                                                async: true,
                                                cache: false,
                                                success: function (result) {
                                                    //alert('OK ' + result.success.message)
                                                    update(editId)
                                                },
                                                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                                    alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            $.ajax({
                                                type: "POST",
                                                url: "${resource(dir:'orderItem/savex')}/" + editId,
                                                data: {'productid':prodid, 'quantity':quantity, 'price':price, 'invoiceid':${invoice.id}},
                                                async: true,
                                                cache: false,
                                                success: function (result) {
                                                    var id = result.success.id
                                                    //alert('OK ' + id)
                                                    update(id)
                                                },
                                                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                                    alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    text: "Cancel",
                                    click: function() {
                                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        });
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="dialogEntry" title="Item Entry">
```

Change this to:

```
<div id="dialogEntry" title="Item Entry" style="display:none;">
```

Change this:

```
 document.getElementById("add").innerHTML =
                        $( "#dialogEntry" ).dialog({
```

to

```
 document.getElementById("add").innerHTML =
                        $( "#dialogEntry" ).show().dialog({
```

Change this to:

```
text: "Cancel",
                                    click: function() {
                                        $( this ).dialog( "close" ).hide();
                                    }
```

Comment: Whilst above should hopefully work. If it is possible you should look into having a a central dialog box maybe a template you render within your gsp that contains the dialog box. The content should then be dynamically added to dialog box. A little more complex but much tidier than above method

Comment: Thank you! that was a simple and fast solution! It worked perfectly. As for having a central dialog box, I'll look into it in the future, I'm still new with programming in gsp :)

Comment: this will be a great start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694693/how-to-have-jqueryui-dialog-box-dynamically-load-content - basically and follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420897/sending-an-error-in-grails-and-reading-it-in-javascript to get jquery to load the content into the relevant div ..